# why I can not mapping my java spring successully?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

My project is has Java as sever and Angularjs as client part. 
Project can be run successfully but get `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).` when calling `http://localhost:8080/login`.
 I feel I do not set up `web.xml` correctly, but I am not so sure what is the right one.

The one error from commend line is

```
2015-10-29 14:32:58.229  WARN 1847 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

The structure of this project is as

```
loginservice/src/main
>java
  >config
    >webMVCConfig.java
    >LoginServiceInitializer.java
  >controller
    >LoginController.java
  ...
>resources
>webapp
  >static
    >js (Angularjs Code)
    >css
  >WEB-INF
     >views
       >login.jsp (html page)
```

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login()
    {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

webMVCConfig.java

```
   @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionIDInterceptor transactionIdInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(transactionIdInterceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

LoginServiceInitializer.java

```
public class LoginServiceInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter() };
        return singleton;
    }
```

}

Comment: Try using `WEB-INF` (uppercase) for you directory name

Comment: @RC. It is uppercase already.

Comment: Now that you have edited, yes it is :)

Comment: @RC. but it still does not work